# Millions of rows in GUI

Tags: linux, user-interface, gtk

I would like to implement a GUI handling a huge number of rows and I need to use `GTK` in Linux.

I started having a look at `GTKTreeView` with lists but I don't think that adding millions of lines directly to that widget will help in having a GUI that doesn't slow the application.

Do you know whether there is a `GTK` widget already in place for this problem or do I have to handle my self the window frame that that must display those lines? Eventually I would write the data directly using `GtkDrawingArea` (essentially writing a new widget).

Any suggestion about any `GTK` topic or project I can look as starting point for my research?

Comment: You can use `gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func()` as recommended [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2007-June/msg00003.html).

Comment: Hi Frederic! Thanks for your response. I think yours is right answer as I can call on the fly the data. Thanks for pointing me out this. p.s. if you response not as comment I might accept your answer as correct as I think it is.

Comment: Thank you :) Right now my comment has not enough material for an answer I'm afraid, but if you write some code that uses this function and end up encountering an issue you want to ask about, you will only have to update your question with that code to receive more elaborate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the Cell Data Func, and get the displayed data under contro. But I have another idea: Millions of lines are much much more than any amount of information a human user can see and understand. So maybe a better, more usable and user-friendly solution, is to diaplay the data in a way the users can more easily navigate in it.

Imagine opening a huge hierarchy, scrolling down, and forgetting what were the top-level items you opened.

Example for a possible solution: Have a combo box which allows to choose some filter or category, and this can reduce the amount of data to a reasonable amount the user can more easily navigate and make a mental model of it if necessary.

NOTE: As far as I know, GtkTreeView doesn't support sorting/filtering and drag-n-drop at the same time, so if you want to use both features, I suggest you use the existing drag-n-drop functionality (otherwise very complicated to implement by hand) and implement your own sorting/filtering.